# Assign same parrent Page to pages AND custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, pages, slug

I have a page, where I list our current free job positions, let's call it `Career`. In it's content all custom post types of type `job_position` are being displayed.

For some specific reasons I need to have couple of subpages, which have the `Career` page set as their Parrent page (so it displays correctly in breadcrumbs, etc.)

The problem is that once you click some job position, a single CTP page displays like this:

Slug: `mysite.com/job_position/job-name` instead of `mysite.com/career/job-name`

Breadcrumbs: `Home > Job name` instead of `Job > Career > Job name`

I can workaround this by setting the custom slug for my CPT's (either with CPT UI plugin, which I use, or programatically). After that, both slug and breadcrumbs work great for these CPT, but all subpages that have the `Career` page set as their parrent throw a 404 error (because I messed up the permalink structure by those changes).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use custom rewrite rules to handle requests to the child "Career" Pages.